# Tool to use the VirusTotal malware scanner more efficiently

Tags: security, workflow, antivirus

Once or twice every day, I want to scan a group of 1-3 files on [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) for malware, and about twice every week, I want to check a group of 5-10 files.

I find using the VirusTotal website very inefficient for performing these simple tasks.  It only allows me to check one file at a time, and it asks me to complete a time-consuming (and, frankly, annoying) Google reCaptcha before it allows me to check an additional file after checking a single file.

It often takes me 3-15 minutes to perform a task that need only take 1 minute at most.

Please recommend a tool that allows me to use VirusTotal more efficiently.  The tool can be a web-app or a Windows application.

Gratis options are preferred, but all recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I read that [Process Expolorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) form SysInternals/Microsoft has a built in function to send files to VirusTotal, see https://blog.malwarebytes.com/cybercrime/2014/01/process-explorer-now-including-virustotal-support/

Answer (score 0):

Many tools are mentioned on the VirusTotal website [1]. Because the official **Windows Uploader** is unmaintained they recommend this VirusTotal Uploader [2].

[1] https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002179065-Desktop-Apps
[2] https://github.com/SamuelTulach/VirusTotalUploader

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  How does that application differ from the VirusTotal website?  Looking at the gif animation on the GitHub page, the app seems to only offer scanning 1 file at a time.  Also it seems to just send the hash of the file to the VirusTotal website, which is pretty much what the VirusTotal website already does (which results in a reCaptcha challenge after the first file for me).  Does it do more than that?